# Nextbook 8 internal storage error

Tags: internal-storage, nextbook-premium-8

So my nextbook 8 tablet has always been very finicky. I can do with the power button troubles and everything, but theres one thing that made my tablet near useless. I was on a trusted app, when suddenly my tablet froze, and stayed frozen for almost 12 hours. When i finally was able to restart my device, it had performed a factory reset, which means all my apps were gone. Every single one. But the memory in the internal storage still appears as if i still had all my applications. I am left with 121MB of storage space which is unusable, and my tablet is showing nothing that could be using up my storage space. The downloads screen shows the "no apps installed message" when i open it up. How can I fix this?